# Writing IMU accelerometer data into as twist messages into cmd_vel

Tags: ros, imu, accelerometer, python

I am reading accelerometer data from the wiimote **/wiimote/state** topic.

A sample of the data I'm working with is as follows:

```
angular_velocity_raw:
  x: 8292.0
  y: 8246.0
  z: 8182.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.1915446291709091, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3915998474972723, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5571460438609092]
linear_acceleration_zeroed:
  x: -3.63209259259
  y: -1.45283703704
  z: 8.67511346154
linear_acceleration_raw:
  x: 120.0
  y: 128.0
  z: 154.0
```

From running the turtlebot3_teleop node I can see that the range of data on the linear-x axis is **-2.84 to 2.84** while on the angular-y axis it's **-0.22 to 0.22**. 
My problem is the x axis the data I retrieve from the accelerometer is much larger. For instance, from the output above, *angular_velocity_raw.z* has a value of *8182.0* **and** *linear_acceleration_raw.x* has a value of *120.0*.

**Can anyone help me with advice on how I can accurately make my accelerometer figures fit into the specified ranges mentioned above?**